# How to make a section with image and text side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how to create a section like this in bootstrap [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CXXX.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly provide your code and explain what is not working. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most use bootstrap grid also for space from top in text grid you need to use [padding-top](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-top.asp) attribute

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6" style='padding-top: 50px;'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6" style="background-image: url('/images/bg.png')">
</div>
</div>
```

also i suggest to you for read this article for understand different size: https://codepen.io/team/MedTouch/full/YqBJzv

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 bg-grey">
....Your text here
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-image: url('/images/bg.png')">
</div>
</div>
```

depends on your screenshot this code might help